# How is spatial search implemented at the code level in solar or elasticsearch

Tags: search, elasticsearch, solr, lucene

Since lucene is developed purely in java , can i find out how spatial is implemented by solar or elasticsearch since they are using lucene

Answer (score 1):

While this is a very broad question, a good place to start is [the github repo for Lucene and Solr](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr). Searching for Solr Spatial will give you [the code for Solr's interface](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/search?l=java&q=Spatial+Solr&utf8=%E2%9C%93) to the Lucene Spatial functionality, and gives you the names of classes (and by looking at the imports, what the important parts in the Lucene code base is).

After digging through a bit of code, looking at [AbstractSpatialFieldType](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/360b9a35282a005fd4a9acddfafb3814592baba8/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/schema/AbstractSpatialFieldType.java) for fields defined as spatial field types in Solr seems to be a good place to dig further into the Solr implementation.

In addition I can recommend looking up the spatial talks from the previous years of Lucene Solr Revolution, where you should be able to find down-to-the-metal-talks about the implementation (and the evolution it has been through the last years). David Smiley has been heading the implementation from the Solr side (which also includes a lot of the Lucene side as far as I understand).